# Find all numbers $x$ and $y$ such as that $ ^yx \ =\ ^xy$.

Tags: number-theory, tetration

Find all integers $x$ and $y$ such as that $ ^yx \ =\ ^xy$, where $^yx$ is a tetration.

Can it also be solved in real numbers?

I already know this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration.

I tried experimenting a little, as well as trying to solve it, but I soon found out that it's out of my scope. I am asking for a solution here because I am highly interested in it and I haven't seen a post about it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Or are you just tossing off a problem you think is hard?

Comment: Can you see any solutions by experimenting?

Comment: Well, $x$ and $y$ must have the same prime factors. And $x=y$ is of course solutions so wolog $x< y$.  I think we get severe telescoping issues.

Comment: If Lambert W cannot help, we possibly need I. N. Galidakis: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions, 2007.

Comment: I tried experimenting a little, as well as trying to solve it, but I soon found out that it's out of my scope. I am asking for a solution here because I am highly interested in it and I haven't seen a post about it.

Comment: @IV_ Hi, thanks for the name push. I'm really busy at the moment trying to not go totally broke financially, so I am not checking the forum very often. I'll write a couple of things about it in a while if the question stays open.

Comment: @spock. Hi, it's only obliviously and stupidly occluded by the demon until you notice the obvious: ${^x}y={^y}x\Rightarrow x|y\wedge y|x\Rightarrow x=\pm y$, from elementary Number Theory. Since there's no clear consensus on what ${^{-y}}x$ means, I am throwing this case out. For at least one $x$ or $y$ non-integer (say $y$), there's also no common consensus on how ${^y}x$ should be interpreted, so again there's no question about that. Briefly, the only solutions to this equation are $x=y$ with $x\in\mathbb{N}$.